# Assigning a R matrix from a list into a Sage list

Tags: r, for-loop, sage

I have an R list (actually a list of list of list) that contains data i want to run a convex optimization procedure on in SAGE.

The code goes like this

```
sage_list = [None] * 2
for k in range(2):
    x = r('my_r_list[[1]][[1]][[k+1]]')
    sage_list[k] = x._sage_()
```

First the `x` assignment is not consistent. If i execute several times the same code i obtain different data. But more importantly the `sage_list[k]` assignment gives an error:

```
NameError: name 'structure' is not defined
```

doing the following however works:

```
sage_list = [None] * 2
x = r('my_r_list[[1]][[1]][[1]]')
y = r('my_r_list[[1]][[1]][[2]]')
sage_list[0] = x._sage_()
sage_list[1] = y._sage_()
```

any idea of why? (of course in reality i have much more than 2 iterations)

Comment: It seems to me that in your for loop you are using `k` expecting it to change the argument of `r` and consequently `x`. However `k` in that instance is just seen as a string, I don't think you are substituting your loop variable value there. Try: `x = r(paste0("my_r_list[[1]][[1]][[",k+1,"]]")`

Answer (score 0):

This solution actually works

```
x = r('my_r_list')[[1]][[1]][[k+1]]
```

`r()` yields and `RElement` type of object over which R indexing works.